# Masking words in HTML/JS/JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Slightly odd question.

Is there a way to quickly mask words in HTML5 JS Jquery? so for example I have the abbreviation:

DU
EG
PAC

I want these to remain as they are for all intents and purposes BUT on the front side of my page just provide a "mask" of some sort to show them with their full wording.

Sort of like a Find and Replace but only temporary so when a page loads, find all instances of DU (full word, match case) and then replace  with a temporary mask "Department Unity".

If not and it's just a case of changing it to the full wording and changing it back is there a reason why it could not be done?

I apologize if this is a bit vague or doesn't make sense!

Comment: What is the duration of "temporary" ?

Comment: Until a user leaves that page? and when they return the "mask" is then implemented again?

Comment: See OP at _"but only temporary"_ ? _"Until a user leaves that page?"_ Is this "temporary" ?  You want to replace displayed words permanently, no ? Not certain interpret requirement correctly ? At page load word is changed, after a few seconds word changes back to original word ? Or change word and leave remain changed ?

Comment: I want to mask them, not replace. So for the time period that a user is on that page, the abbreviation DU is displayed as "Department Unity" but in the background of the page the code relies on it being "DU" so it only needs to display visually as Department Unity. It's quite hard to explain what I want to achieve but hopefully that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to mask them, not replace. So for the time period that a user
>   is on that page, the abbreviation DU is displayed as "Department
>   Unity" but in the background of the page the code relies on it being
>   "DU" so it only needs to display visually as Department Unity.

You can set `DOM` element `color` to `transparent` ; set `css` `:before` pseudo replaced element `color` property to `#000` , `content` property to replacement text to be displayed

```css
.word {
  color:transparent;
}
.word:before {
  color:#000;
}
.word:nth-of-type(1):before {
  content: "Department Unity";
}
.word:nth-of-type(2):before {
  content: "Ethereal Gravity";
}
.word:nth-of-type(3):before {
  content: "Purple Ambient Cascade";
}
```

```html
<div class="word">DU</div>
<div class="word">EG</div>
<div class="word">PAC</div>
```

---

> Is there a way to define the abbreviations in the CSS, like you have
>   defined the replacements. For instance, instead of applying .word
>   class, I would say all instances of DU or EG or PAC and replace with
>   the corresponding word? or does it have to have a class attached?

Yes. You can substitute the abbreviate as a `className` for `.word` which will display the `:before` `content` at each element having that `className` within the `document`

```css
.DU, .EG, .PAC {
  color:transparent;
  font-size:0px;
}
.DU:before, .EG:before, .PAC:before {
  color:#000;
  font-size:16px !important;
}
.DU:before {
  content: "Department Unity";
}
.EG:before {
  content: "Ethereal Gravity";
}
.PAC:before {
  content: "Purple Ambient Cascade";
}
```

```html
<span class="DU">DU</span> shared
<span class="EG">EG</span> at 
<span class="PAC">PAC</span> before returning to <span class="DU">DU</span> by way of <span class="EG">EG</span> through the <span class="PAC">PAC</span>
```

Comment: Is there a way to define the abbreviations in the CSS, like you have defined the replacements. For instance, instead of applying .word class, I would say all instances of DU or EG or PAC and replace with the corresponding word? or does it have to have a class attached?

Comment: @MrDansk Yes. There are several approaches which could be used to achieve expected results. Composed a `javascript` version using `.replace()` before you clarified that word should not actually be replaced within `document`. You could substitute the abbreviation for the `.word` `className`; at each `.DU`, `.EG` or `.PAC` element within the `document`, the pseudo element `content` would be displayed.

Comment: Well, maybe I can clarify a bit more. The values are held in the second column of a table. I've managed to apply your initial response and give all the TD elements in column 2 the class "word" however, this seems to be renaming column 2's heading and the content of all the TD's in column 2 to only one of the words. i.e it makes them all "Department Unity" including the header?

Comment: @MrDansk Well, you did not include the `html` that are using at Question ? Original Question does not describe of use of `table` element, `tr`, or `td` or any specific elements; or what exact result should be other than to "mask" the original text content of the element. Perhaps update Question with the `html` that you are using and describe what the expected result is ? See updated post for an alternative approach

Comment: Apologies, initially I think I was just trying to get across whether there was a "masking method" available. I was unsure so I didn't think the extra detail would add anything to the question at that point but thanks for the extra work! I will try and see if I can implement and then come back to mark the answer.

Comment: @MrDansk No worries. See also [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) , [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 1):

Can you modify the HTML-markup? Here is one example that works as "masking". Just replace data-word= with your abbreviation

Html:

```
<p data-word="DU"></p>
<p data-word="EG"></p>
<p data-word="PAC"></p>
```

CSS:

```
p[data-word=DU]:before {
  content: "Department Unity";
}

p[data-word=EG]:before {
  content: "E.. G..";
}

p[data-word=PAC]:before {
  content: "P.. A.. C..";
}
```

Comment: I think to modify the HTML i would have to loop through all the TD elements and check their value in javascript/jquery. If they contained one of my abbreviations then add a class to that TD element like class="DU" and then do the replacement.

Comment: In that case the best way to replace each word is with pure js? I don't understand why you are not using `$("td").each(function(){

var word = $(this).text();
case..switch

});`

Answer (score 0):

A more dynamic and manipulated approach here with jQuery.
It would retain original value, hide it and displays the 'masked' value.

The actual DOM would be changed but every instance would be tagged and retrievable afterwards:

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    var maskPairs = [
        ["DU", "Department Unity"],
        ["EG", "Evil Grin :D"],
        ["PAC", "Perfectly Artificial Coincidence"]
    ];

    $(".mask-me").each(function performMasking() {
        var elem = $(this);
        $.each(maskPairs, function (i, pair) {
            var searchRegExp = new RegExp("\\b(" + pair[0] + ")\\b", "g");
            var replaceValue = "<span class=\"masked-word\">$1</span><span class=\"word-masking\" title=\"$1\">" + pair[1] + "</span>";
            elem.html(elem.html().replace(searchRegExp, replaceValue));
        });
    });

});
```

CSS:

```
.masked-word {
  display: none
}
.word-masking{
  border-bottom: 1px dotted #000;
}
```

Sample HTML:

```
<div class="mask-me">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit DU amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
    Morbi EG rhoncus erat lorem, eu dictum felis DU finibus consequat.
    Morbi EG interdum velit non massa imperdiet, PAC nec feugiat elit elementum.
    Ut maximus lectus a elit tempor, PAC sit amet aliquet ante finibus.
    <ul>
        <li>Nulla facilisi. Cras viverra PAC lectus sapien. Proin vel velit turpis.</li>
        <li>Donec eleifend DU dignissim felis, eu gravida diam vestibulum sed.</li>
    </ul>
    <div>
        Donec DU tristique vestibulum feugiat.
        <p>
            Donec sodales lobortis arcu ac PAC blandit. Maecenas varius posuere EG nibh ut laoreet.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        Donec tristique vestibulum feugiat.
        <p>
            Donec sodales lobortis arcu ac blandit. Maecenas varius posuere nibh ut laoreet.
        </p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Sample output: [here (JS Bin Link)](http://output.jsbin.com/nosawiyazi)

The original abbreviations would be wrapped in a span with the class `masked-word` and the replaced instance would be wrapped in a span with the class `word-masking`

[JS Bin Sample](http://jsbin.com/nosawiyazi)

Comment: _"I want to mask them, not replace."_ http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36418862/masking-words-in-html-js-jquery/36419541?noredirect=1#comment60452956_36418862